# Add a variable with several levels to columns in pivot table R

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot-table

I have a code for the pivot table that looks like this:

| var1 | var2 | var3 | Sum_in_items | Sum_in_money |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | First | 1 | 10 | 500 |
| Second | Second | 2 | 12 | 500 |

And it looks like this:

```
db %>%                        
  group_by(var1, var2, var3) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(Sum_in_items = round(sum(items)), 
                   Sum_in_money = sum(money))
```

However, I also have var4 which has several levels (var1, var2, and var3 are also factors) and I need to add these levels of var4 as columns to the table. It should look like in the photo. I am sorry I cannot create the table here. [image: The photo of desired output]

I am super new at pivot tables and my formulations might be strange, please ask questions if you have any. I know how to do such thing in tableau (I just drag var4 into columns but here it is harder).

Comment: Is the first table you provided `db` or is that table the result of the following code? Can you provide your entire dataset or produce a reproducible example that includes `var4`? See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example